# React Reflux: onUpdate#this.trigger(rows) causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

I have a React component that displays radio buttons. Changes to these should be handled by Reflux. As I understand it `this.trigger(object)` should be called to save any changes to the object. Unfortunately that causes an infinite loop.

I have posted an [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/stabenfeldt/1tk0svja/) that demonstrates the error.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? How should `onUpdateAutoComplete(checked)` be crafted?

```
<AutoCompleteFrom autocomplete_from={form_fields.autocomplete_from} />
```

**The checkbox component**

```
var AutoCompleteFrom = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Reflux.connect(store)],

  render: function() {
    var autocompleteFrom = this.props.autocomplete_from.map(function(value) {
      return (
        <label for={value}>
          <input type="radio" name={'autocomplete_from'+this.props.id} value={value}
            onChange={actions.updateAutoComplete(this.props.checked)} 
            checked={this.props.checked == value}
          />
          {value}
        </label>
      );
    }, this);
    return (
      <div className="autocomplete-from">
        {autocompleteFrom}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**onUpdateAutoComplete**

```
  onUpdateAutoComplete(checked){
    console.log('checked:', checked);
    rows[0].autocomplete_from = checked;
    // this.trigger(rows); // <== Causes an infinite loop when included.
  },
```

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to call `onChange={actions.handleChange}` and have that triggering `actions.updateAutoComplete(event.target.value, event.target.name);`

Fiddle is updated with working code.